# Extracting all keyframes with FFmpeg as quickly as possible from .mp4

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, decoding

From other answers here I've found this to be the supposedly quickest way to extract all keyframes from .mp4 videos:

```
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i in -vf "scale=320:-1" -vsync 0 -q:v 2 out%07d.png
```

However, when I try this on a 7.9 second .mp4 file, only 2 frames are outputted where I would expect 8 since the video is 30 fps and keyframes are once every 30 frames in this file.

Comment: Share the file. Note that not all I-frames are KFs.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bgoz8fgx9k8sus/short.mp4?dl=0
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think I must be misunderstanding the difference between I-frames and keyframes in this context.

Comment: Only frames at times 0 and 4.004 are KF, other I frames are non-KF.

Comment: KF are frames required by other frames for decoding; I-frames are frames which can be decoded independently. All KFs are I-frames but not all I-frames are KFs.